# Figures in tables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, floats

I want to make a table with lots of figures.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
Index   & Stand. Residuals & acf\\ \hline\hline
BEL 20  & \vspace{-10pt}\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{res_B}\vspace{-10pt} & \vspace{-10pt}\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{acf_B}\vspace{-10pt} \\ \hdashline
CAC 40  & \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{res_C}\vspace{-10pt} & \vspace{-10pt}\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{acf_B}\vspace{-10pt}\\ \hdashline
DAX & \vspace{-10pt}\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{res_D} \vspace{-10pt} & \vspace{-10pt}\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{acf_B}\vspace{-10pt}\\ \hdashline
FTSE 100    & \vspace{-10pt}\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{res_F}\vspace{-10pt} & \vspace{-10pt}\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{acf_B}\vspace{-10pt}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The problem is that i want my text in the first column to be horizantally centered. Without having too much trouble with the size of my figures. This is what i get (don't look at the size of the figures i will manage that, for instance only the first 4 indices).

[image]

Comment: What goes wrong with the centering? If you cannot supply a minimal working example, can you supply an image showing your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is far from clear.

The first column you say you want horizontally centred but it already is (because of the `c` column specification) Do you mean you want it vertically centred with respect to the image?

The second column is a `c` column which is a horizontal (LR) box like `mbox` so you can not use `\vspace`. To lower an image by half its natural height you can use

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics...}
```

as this will put the baseline through the centre of the image it will effectively move the text in the first column. as an alternative to `\raisebox` you can use the `adjustbox` package which offers a nicer interface.

Comment: That helped a lot. Still there is a lot of space between my horizontal lines and the figures. How can i change that? Without changing the fact that my text in the first column is vertically centred with respect to the image.

Comment: There should be no space try putting `\fbox{..}` around the `\includegraphics` just for debugging. if the space comes inside teh fbox then it is part of the image and you need to get rid of it either in an external editor or using the bb(bounding box) or trim optopns to `\includegraphics`